# Wasm streaming compile failed in Unity WebXR Exporter Build

Tags: webserver, web-hosting, webassembly, unity-webgl, webxr

I'm building a WebXR Exporter project from the De-Panther package on Unity 2020 on my subdomain which is hosted by Hostinger on an Apache server.  I'm using gzip and I believe that Unity is attempting WebAssembly streaming automatically

When I try to run on my webpage on Chrome I get this these on the console:

wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.

WebGL Build.loader.js:1 HTTP Response Header "Content-Type" configured incorrectly on the server for file Build/WebGL Build.wasm.gz , should be "application/wasm". Startup time performance will suffer.

This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddEncoding gzip .unityweb
    AddEncoding gzip .wasm
    AddType application/wasm .wasm
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    RemoveType .gz
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
    AddType application/octet-stream .data.gz
    AddType application/wasm .wasm.gz
    AddType application/javascript .js.gz
    AddType application/octet-stream .symbols.json.gz
</IfModule>
```

Is this incorrect?  I got it from a Unity help page...

I am very new to servers so please let me know if I missed in important info